# JavaScript array Sort out! Indices problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given an array A of non-negative integers of size **m**. Your task is to sort the array in non-decreasing order and print out the original indices of the new sorted array.
e.g.A={4,5,3,7,1}

After sorting the new array becomes A={1,3,4,5,7}.

The required output should be "4 2 0 1 3"

Comment: what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying this, but not accepting all the test cases.

Comment: i asked you a question, for this to achieve what you try to get answer.

Comment: let arr = [401, 501, 301, 701, 101],
  result = "";

let obj = new Object();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[arr[i]] = i;
}
for (x in obj) {
  result += obj[x] + " ";
}
console.log(result);

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pair (tuple) the value with the original index. After mapping the tuples, sort by the value and finally map the original (now sorted) indices.

```js
const sortValuesAndGetOriginalIndices = (arr) => arr
  .map((element, index) => [element, index])
  .sort(([v1], [v2]) => v1 - v2)
  .map(([value, index]) => index);

const arr = [4, 5, 3, 7, 1];
const indices = sortValuesAndGetOriginalIndices(arr);

console.log(...indices); // [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

If you want to return the sorted values and the indicies, you can reduce at the end:

```js
const enhancedSort = (arr) => arr
  .map((element, index) => [element, index])
  .sort(([v1], [v2]) => v1 - v2)
  .reduce(({ values, indices }, [v, i]) =>
    ({
      values: [...values, v],
      indices: [...indices, i]
    }),
    { values: [], indices: [] });

const arr = [4, 5, 3, 7, 1];
const { values, indices } = enhancedSort(arr);

console.log(...values);  // [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
console.log(...indices); // [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the indices and sort only the indices array by the values of the given data.

```js
const
    array = [4, 5, 3, 7, 1],
    indices = [...array.keys()].sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]);

console.log(...indices);
```